# Django-Registration-Redux doesn't see my templates/registration templates

Tags: django-registration, django-1.10

I am using Django 1.10.  Technically this post is regarding Django-registration-redux but SO wouldnt let me create a new tag to post the question. Django-registration-redux doesnt see the registration templates.  I copied all the templates into a folder called "registration" inside of my templates folder.  I dont get an error though.  For example, when I go to /accounts/register it renders some form but it isn't the one from my templates/register folder. Im not sure what I am doing wrong.  I have even gone as far as to delete the templates/registration folder entirely and I dont even get an error. I read some similar posts where people had to move the registration to the top of the installed apps so it wouldnt use the admin forms which I tried and didnt help. So far nothing has changed.  All the templates do extend base.

So Im guessing I have configured something wrong.  It's weird.  All the functionality is there but its just not using my templates.  Sorry if its a dumb question but I would appreciate some help!

```
pip freeze
Django==1.10
django-crispy-forms==1.6.0
django-registration-redux==1.4

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'registration',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # third party
    'crispy_forms',
    # my apps
    'todo',
]



# Django registration redux settings
ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7
REGISTRATION_OPEN = True
REGISTRATION_AUTO_LOGIN = True
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'  # The page you want users to arrive at after they successful log in
LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login/'

SITE_ID = 1
```

Here is my /templates/registration/registration_form.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
<div class='row'>
<div class='col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'>
<h1>Register for free!</h1>
<form method="post" action=".">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form|crispy }}

  <input class='btn btn-block btn-primary' type="submit" value="{% trans 'Join' %}" />
</form>
</div>
</div>

<hr/>
<div class='row'>
<div class='col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 text-align-center'>
<p>Need to <a href="{% url 'auth_login' %}">Login</a>?</p>
</div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

[this is a screenshot showing the form I see at accounts/register](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2j8R.png)

Comment: I was able to get it working but this cant be the best way.  I went into my virtualenv's site packages to the django registration package and found the template folder containing the templates it was actually rendering.  Just to test, I renamed that template folder in the actual django registration app to registration_temp and I guess when it could no longer find its own templates that forced it to see my templates.  Is there a setting I am missing that tells django registration to use its own templates or yours?  I installed using pip so I'd think other people would come across this too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In settings.py you have to place your app above the 'registration' app.  It seems the order the apps are listed in the settings.py file determines which templates are being used.

Comment: sorry for the delay in the response.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Next time try making a directory relating to your app's name in the app templates folder. For instance, if you have an app called "register" call the folder "register" in the templates folder of your app and then put all your templates in there. This would prevent templates named index.html in both app templates folder and the main project templates folder from conflict with each other.